# testcafe higher order selector

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, selector, testcafe

I am trying to create a higher order selector which I can reuse by changing a text parameter. In the snippet below, when I am trying to perform `t.click` using `actualSelector`, it's not working as expected. When I console log the value for the `actualSelector`, i see whole item values are printed.

Seems I am not using it right way. Can you please help me with this.

e.g

```
const testItemNameGenericSelector = (itemName) =>
    Selector(
      ".ms-Callout-container .ms-Callout-main  div div"
    )
  .withText(itemName);
...
  const itemNameToSelect = "Test Item-8ab1ec12-e719-4ab6-a0a3-ed538143d6d3";
  const actualSelector = testItemNameGenericSelector(itemNameToSelect)
...
  console.log(`selecting ${await actualSelector().textContent}`)
```

Below is full testcafe code for this test.

```
fixture`Getting Started`
  .page // declare the fixture
`https://hasans30.github.io/testpage/dropdown.html`; // specify the start page

//then create a test and place your code there
test("My first test", async (t) => {

   const testItemNameGenericSelector = (itemName) =>
    Selector(
      ".ms-Callout-container .ms-Callout-main  div div"
    )
  .withText(itemName);
  const buttonSelector = Selector('.ms-Button-label');
  const selectedValue = Selector('.ms-Dropdown-title');

  const itemNameToSelect = "Test Item-8ab1ec12-e719-4ab6-a0a3-ed538143d6d3";
  const actualSelector = testItemNameGenericSelector(itemNameToSelect);


  await t.click(buttonSelector,{speed:0.51})
  console.log(`selecting ${await actualSelector().textContent}`)

  await t.click(actualSelector,{speed:0.51})
  await t.expect(await selectedValue().textContent).eql(itemNameToSelect);

});
```

Comment: Can you post the selector as it is shown in the elements tab of your browser? I'm not sure if it works if you have spaces inside the string, for me at least it doesnt.

Comment: This gives me hint. I have to use till button in selector.  
below selector works.
".ms-Callout-container .ms-Callout-main  div div button"

Comment: Well, I'm glad it does. The reason I was asking is because this selector  does not work for me .flex.flex-row bg-red rounded-full.p-1 but this one does div.flex.flex-row.bg-red.rounded-full.p-1. Replace the space with a dot. Also, you could make that selector as a function, such as: async testItemSelector(itemname: string) {await t.click(Selector(".ms-Callout-container.ms-Callout-main.div.div").withText(itemname))} then just call this function during your test like await this.testItemSelector(itemname = 'this item name')